# How to set a Loopback nodeJS backend on Apache HTTP server running on CentOS

Tags: node.js, linux, apache, centos, loopback

I've moved the backend (nodeJs+Loopback) of my application on a server CentOS. When I run it, it's listening on "localhost:3000". If I type "curl http://localhost:3000" while I'm on the server's terminal I get a response. When I try to call the application from remote, I use the real IP address instead of localhost, but it doesn't work.

The error is:

```
[proxy:error] (13)Permission denied:HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3000(localhost) failed
```

Do I need to setup some configuration?

Thank you

Comment: It can be a firewall or proxy issue. Can you do a telnet test from where you are trying to access your application on the IP and port and see if it is successful ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @xan_z the problem was a flag named httpd_can_network_connect which wasn't at 1 so the server couldn't accept http requests.

Comment: @jww thank you, i'll take notice of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1` ??

Check out the bottom of this link:

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied

Comment: That's correct! I've found this solution too, thank you!